# Is it possible to distribute a proccess's cpu across several computers?

Tags: c++, process, distributed-computing

Im trying to implement Distributed calculation in order to help me brute force some encryptions(like one time pad), and I wanted to know if its possible to allocate some of the memmory that the process uses across several computers, and if I can-how?
Im coding in cpp

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is *WAY* out of scope for an SO question. I suggest you do some research on HPC techniques and more specific technologies such as MPI or Spark

Comment: It's often way easier to distribute the _problem_. For instance, brute force searches are trivial. That means you're checking each and every instance in the search space. Just distribute that search space.